# Linear Layout not scrolling

Tags: android, layout, scroll, scrollbar, scrollview

I have created a fragment and its xml code is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.unss.pra.b.one_fragment"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">




        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Download"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/textView07"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                android:id="@+id/dbutton1"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:id="@+id/textView08"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"

                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textView02"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton2" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton2"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView05"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"

                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textView04"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton4" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton4"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>






            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text=" Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"

                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton5" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton5"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>







            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView06"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"

                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton6" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton6"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>





            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"

                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView09"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"

                    android:id="@+id/textView03"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/dbutton7" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/downloadicon"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton7"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
            </RelativeLayout>






        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Keeping the idea:
Linear/Relative Layout
Scroll View
Linear Layout
//My layouts,

I have put Linear Scroll view, the layout is not getting scrolled. The layout just remains static. Please let me know why.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `Scrollview` to : add `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">
```

Comment: try putting the scrollview as the parent tag of the layout..<Scrollview><Relativelayout>

Comment: When I tried doing so, it removes everything including action bar.

Comment: run it on device

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, Removed a lot of lines of drawables and project info as it is customized for your own project. 
The code is working fine, I can scroll. Maybe the problem lies in the images you are using, High res images sometimes do make your UI unresponsive / freeze. Make sure you look into that too.

I am attaching your code and a snapshot of how it appears to me. Code works fine.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">
           <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textView07"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton1" />
            </RelativeLayout>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="\n"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:typeface="serif"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:id="@+id/textView08"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               />


           <RelativeLayout
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:paddingRight="10dp">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:text="Download"
                   android:textSize="20dp"
                   android:typeface="serif"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:id="@+id/textView02"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

               <Button
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                   android:layout_height="50dp"
                   android:id="@+id/dbutton2"
                   />
           </RelativeLayout>

           <TextView
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:text="\n"
               android:textSize="20dp"
               android:typeface="serif"
               android:textColor="#000000"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
               />


           <RelativeLayout
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:paddingLeft="10dp"
               android:paddingRight="10dp">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:text="Download"
                   android:textSize="20dp"
                   android:typeface="serif"
                   android:textColor="#000000"
                   android:textAlignment="center"
                   android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
               <Button
                   android:layout_width="50dp"
                   android:layout_height="50dp"

                   />
           </RelativeLayout>




            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView05"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/textView04"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton4"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text=" Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView6"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/dbutton5" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView06"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView10"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                     />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="\n"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:typeface="serif"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:id="@+id/textView09"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Download"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:typeface="serif"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:id="@+id/textView03"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                   />

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have used a simple download image of 6 KB. But the fragment is not getting scrolled.

Comment: Upload the project on Git, will look into it then. Else, Compare your code with my formatted one, since it works and I can scroll. So compare and look out for errors.

Comment: It might as you said. Sometimes when I open the app, I get everything without the scroll while other time, the last element gets cut partially or completely. It is because of UI?